# Where $f(x) = \frac{x}{x^2+1}$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis

On which set is $f(x) = \frac{x}{x^2+1}$ continuous? What method do you use to solve these questions?

Comment: Do you know what "continuous" means?

Comment: If you can draw the function without removing your pen from the paper

Comment: @RonnyDeKoning: $f:\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=1/x$ is continuous.

Comment: For future reference, since you've already received a wide array of answers: Please add information about what you know related to your question (in this example, it would have been helpful if you put what you know about continuity or limits, since continuity is DEFINED in terms of limits, but that's clearly not how you understand it yet) so we can give appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first here is a plot of the function

[image]

For example we could use the test that $\frac{f}{g}$ with $f$ and $g$ continuous, is continuous when $g\neq 0$.

Beside this we could use the sequence definition of continuousity
$$\lim f(x_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x_n}{x_n^2 +1 } = \frac{\lim x_n}{\lim x_n^2 +1 }= \frac{x}{x^2+1} = f(\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n)$$

If you are interested i can give you more tests

We will formulize the drwaing without removing the pen form the paper definition.
The thing which fits that most is the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ defintion (just ignore the formula I will explain it in words). A function $f$ is continuous in $x_0$ when
$$\forall \varepsilon >0 \, \exists \delta >0\  \text{such that } |x-x_0|< \delta \implies |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\varepsilon$$

you can draw a line when there are no jumps, so that when you go a bit to the right (the left) your function only goes a bit up (or down). This formula says, for every distance of $f(x)$ and $f(x_0)$ you chose, there is always an intervall, around $x_0$ where the values of the function are nearer.

To prove this one here we calculate
$$|f(x)-f(x_0)|=\left| \frac{x}{x^2+1} - \frac{x_0}{x_0^2+1}\right|=\left| \frac{x(x_0^2 +1)-x_0(x^2+1)}{(x_0^2+1) (x^2+1)}\right|$$

Now we say that $x>x_0$, (if not than $-x>-x_0$ and multiplying with $-1$ doesn't matter in the absolute value) so we have
$$\left| \frac{x}{x^2+1} - \frac{x_0}{x_0^2+1}\right|=\left| \frac{x(x_0^2 +1)-x_0(x^2+1)}{(x_0^2+1) (x^2+1)}\right|\leq |x-x_0| \frac{x^2+1}{(x^2+1)(x_0^2+1)}$$

As
$$|x-x_0| \frac{x^2+1}{(x^2+1)(x_0^2+1)}=|x-x_0| \frac{1}{x_0^2+1}\leq |x-x_0|\cdot \frac{1}{2}$$ we see when we move our pencil a bit to the right, we only need to move it $\frac{\text{bit}}{2}$ up (or down).

Comment: I haven't seen yet limits, I have to use another method

Comment: @RonnyDeKoning look again i made one without limits

Answer (score 4):

Rational functions are continuous everywhere they are defined. In this case, the denominator is never zero, so the function is continuous on the real line.

Comment: Yes, but what is the method?

Comment: The method is to find where the function is not defined, i.e. where the denominator is zero... as Jasper said. Yours is never zero.

Answer (score 2):

The set of continuous functions are closed under:

1. ***addition*** : $f(x), g(x)$ continuous $\implies f(x) + g(x)$ continuous.
2. ***multiplication***: $f(x), g(x)$ continuous $\implies f(x) g(x)$ continuous.
3. ***reciprocal*** (when it is defined): $f(x)$ continuous $\implies \frac{1}{f(x)}$ continuous whenever $f(x) \ne 0$.

Start with:

- any constant (e.g. $x \mapsto 1$ ) is a continuous function.
- the identity map $x \mapsto x$ is a continuous function.

We have:

$(2) \implies x^2 = x*x$ is continuous.
$(1) \implies x^2 + 1$ is continuous.
$(3) \implies \frac{1}{x^2 + 1}$ is continuous because $x^2 + 1 \ne 0$ for all $x$.
$(2) \implies \frac{x}{x^2 + 1} = x * \frac{1}{x^2+1}$ is continuous.

See the pattern?

Comment: Yes, and, more generally, the composition of continuous functions is also continuous.

Answer (score 1):

As Jasper Loy said, the "method" for rational functions is to check whether or not the denominator can equal zero. In the case of your example, the denominator cannot be zero, because, for all $x$,  $x^2\ne -1$. In general, if the denominator equals zero, the function is undefined, which means there will be a "hole" in the graph at any $x$ value that makes the denominator zero. (And you will have to lift your pen!)